# C# progress bar and EdtFTPnet Bytestransferred event

Tags: c#, progress-bar, byte

Hello peeps at Stack Overflow, I have a problem that I've been trying to solve since a couple of days. I have a problem in which I want to display via a progress bar, the bytes transferred from the bytes total of a remote file over FTP.

On the documentation it has been written how to use the ftp events from the library using FTPConnection as an exemple, but i cant get it to work with the BytesTransferred event. I define the method into my code but where exactly or how exactly am i suppose to use it with the progressbar, or with the backgroundworker.reportProgress() method?

If anyone has already used it or if you can give me a tip on that, it would be really greatly appreciated. Ive been searching the forums, but the search function is just hell.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using signalR (http://signalr.net/).  It's a communications library for client+server when you need to keep the connection open for a long time, like chats or file uploads.  On the server, I'd set a variable to session, or somewhere, indicating the progress, supposing the server knows the file size. I haven't used it, but it would be where I go for such tasks.